# VBA - changing link source macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have one workbook(I will call it "master" ) with multiple sheets, each is linked to different workbooks in same folder. Every month I make new folder and copy the content of old folder to the new one. Basically I have folder with path "/path/1"(number represents the month) and every month I want to change it to "/path/2" ...then from "/path/2" to "/path/3"  etc.  How would I do that using macro? My idea is that I would have a cell with name of the new folder. And my macro would change the path accordingly. Could you help me?

Comment: So basically you want to change formula with path, am I right?

Comment: @Iowak yes, but it's not even real formula in master WB I just have linked cell like =path/1......C1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your path should something look like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='C:\Users\My_user\Desktop\example_folder\1\[Testowanie_fak1.xlsm]Test'!R1C1"
```

If you want to change the path so your cells will be linked to a different folder all you need to do this is change the formula just a little bit. In this case I added `Month(Date)` which will automatically add number with current month (so now it will add 8).

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='C:\Users\My_user\Desktop\example_folder\" & Month(Date) & "\[Testowanie_fak1.xlsm]Test'!R1C1"
```

Comment: I am sorry for not replying sooner, thank you for your answer, I will try it tomorrow :)

Comment: I played with it today, and it seems to be working just like I want. Thank you once again